# How to implement pagination using "Flight Offers Search" of Amadeus API

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, amadeus

I want to implement pagination using "Flight Offers Search" of Amadeus API. There is no parameter to passing limit and offset using ["Flight Offers Search" of Amadeus API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference).

I have bellow API URL with filter parameter to get flight list

```
https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=JFK&destinationLocationCode=LHR&departureDate=2021-09-02&returnDate=2021-09-05&adults=1&travelClass=ECONOMY¤cyCode=USD&max=10
```

And I got response from API like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count] => 10
            [links] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [self] => https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=JFK&destinationLocationCode=LHR&departureDate=2021-09-02&returnDate=2021-09-05&adults=1&travelClass=ECONOMY¤cyCode=USD&max=10
                )

        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => flight-offer
                    [id] => 1
                    [source] => GDS
                    [instantTicketingRequired] => 
                    [nonHomogeneous] => 
                    [oneWay] => 
                    [lastTicketingDate] => 2021-08-28
                    [numberOfBookableSeats] => 9
                    [itineraries] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [duration] => PT6H50M
                                    [segments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [departure] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [iataCode] => JFK
                                                            [terminal] => 4
                                                            [at] => 2021-09-02T08:15:00
                                                        )

                                                    [arrival] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [iataCode] => LHR
                                                            [terminal] => 3
                                                            [at] => 2021-09-02T20:05:00
                                                        )

                                                    [carrierCode] => VS
                                                    [number] => 26
                                                    [aircraft] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [code] => 789
                                                        )

                                                    [operating] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [carrierCode] => VS
                                                        )

                                                    [duration] => PT6H50M
                                                    [id] => 3
                                                    [numberOfStops] => 0
                                                    [blacklistedInEU] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [duration] => PT8H15M
                                    [segments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [departure] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [iataCode] => LHR
                                                            [terminal] => 3
                                                            [at] => 2021-09-05T10:10:00
                                                        )

                                                    [arrival] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [iataCode] => JFK
                                                            [terminal] => 4
                                                            [at] => 2021-09-05T13:25:00
                                                        )

                                                    [carrierCode] => VS
                                                    [number] => 4007
                                                    [aircraft] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [code] => 764
                                                        )

                                                    [operating] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [carrierCode] => DL
                                                        )

                                                    [duration] => PT8H15M
                                                    [id] => 8
                                                    [numberOfStops] => 0
                                                    [blacklistedInEU] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [price] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [currency] => USD
                            [total] => 709.86
                            [base] => 122.00
                            [fees] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [amount] => 0.00
                                            [type] => SUPPLIER
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [amount] => 0.00
                                            [type] => TICKETING
                                        )

                                )

                            [grandTotal] => 709.86
                        )

                    [pricingOptions] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fareType] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => PUBLISHED
                                )

                            [includedCheckedBagsOnly] => 
                        )

                    [validatingAirlineCodes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => VS
                        )

                    [travelerPricings] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [travelerId] => 1
                                    [fareOption] => STANDARD
                                    [travelerType] => ADULT
                                    [price] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [currency] => USD
                                            [total] => 709.86
                                            [base] => 122.00
                                        )

                                    [fareDetailsBySegment] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [segmentId] => 3
                                                    [cabin] => ECONOMY
                                                    [fareBasis] => NH3X36B1
                                                    [brandedFare] => LIGHT
                                                    [class] => T
                                                    [includedCheckedBags] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [quantity] => 0
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [segmentId] => 8
                                                    [cabin] => ECONOMY
                                                    [fareBasis] => NH3X36B1
                                                    [brandedFare] => LIGHT
                                                    [class] => T
                                                    [includedCheckedBags] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [quantity] => 0
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
)

    [dictionaries] => stdClass Object
        (
            [locations] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [LHR] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cityCode] => LON
                            [countryCode] => GB
                        )

                    [JFK] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cityCode] => NYC
                            [countryCode] => US
                        )

                )

            [aircraft] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [772] => BOEING 777-200/200ER
                    [764] => BOEING 767-400
                    [77W] => BOEING 777-300ER
                    [777] => BOEING 777-200/300
                    [789] => BOEING 787-9
                )

            [currencies] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [USD] => US DOLLAR
                )

            [carriers] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AA] => AMERICAN AIRLINES
                    [KL] => KLM ROYAL DUTCH AIRLINES
                    [AF] => AIR FRANCE
                    [DL] => DELTA AIR LINES
                    [AY] => FINNAIR
                    [VS] => VIRGIN ATLANTIC
                    [BA] => BRITISH AIRWAYS
                )

        )

)
```

There is no limit and offset parameter in this API.
Please guide me how to implement pagination using "Flight Offers Search" of Amadeus API.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The Flight Offers Search API doesn't support pagination, that's why there are not parameters available to pass the limit and offset in the API reference. Checkout the pagination [guide](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/pagination-264) for more information.